# If $a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_{2000}>a_1a_2\ldots a_{2000}$, prove that at least $1990$ of those numbers are equal to $1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality

If $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_{2000}\in\mathbb N$ and$$a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_{2000}>a_1a_2\ldots a_{2000}$$ Prove that at least $1990$ of those numbers are equal to $1$.

That's an unusual problem for me and I have no idea what to even try. Some help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: What are the conditions on the $a_i$?

Comment: The don't have to be if there are no further resutrictions ont he $a_i$'s

Comment: I mean, are the $a_i$'s elements of $\mathbb{N}$, $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{C}$, etc.?

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick I've added the restriction. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wlog. $a_1\le a_2\le\ldots\le a_{2000}$.
Then the left hand side is $\le 2000\cdot a_{2000}$.
If $a_{1989}>1$ the right hand side is $$\ge\underbrace{1\cdot\ldots \cdot 1}_{1988}\cdot \underbrace{2\cdot\ldots\cdot 2}_{11}\cdot a_{2000} =2^{11}a_{2000}$$
and hence too big. Therefore $a_{1989}=1$.
Assume $a_{1990}>1$ (and hence also $a_{2000}\ge 2$). 
Now the left hand side is $\le 1989 + 11a_{2000}$ and the right hand side is $\ge 2^{10}a_{2000}$. We conclude $1989\ge(2^{10}-11)a_{2000}\ge 1013\cdot 2$, contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

You have $$\sum_{i=1}^{2000}\frac{1}{a_1\cdots a_{i-1}\cdot a_{i+1}\cdots a_{2000}}>1$$ Without loss of generality we can assume $a_2\cdots a_{2000}\leq 2000$, otherwise  each summand is less than $1/2000$ and hence the sum is less than $1$. Now suppose there are $1991$ numbers $\geq 2$. Then the product $a_2\cdots a_{2000}\geq 2^{1990}$, which is surely a contradiction.